# Java beans- return type

Tags: java, mysql, javabeans

I am working on a small Java EE web application. The problem I have is related to a sql statement.

```
I have entities messaging and users.

I have a method- getMessagesById(int msgid)

    public Messaging getMessagesByMid(int msgid) {

            String query = "SELECT msgid, msgsubject, msgcontent, timestamp, fname, lname FROM messaging INNER JOIN users ON messaging.users_userid=users.userid WHERE msgid=?;";

            try {
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.clearParameters();
                ps.setInt(1, msgid);

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                Messaging m= new Messaging();
                Users u= new Users();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    m.setMsgid((rs.getInt(1)));
                    m.setMsgsubject(rs.getString(2));
                    m.setMsgcontent(rs.getString(3));
                    m.setTimestamp(rs.getString(4));
                    m.setMsgrecipient(rs.getInt(5));
                    m.setUsers_userid(rs.getInt(6));
                    u.setFname(rs.getString(7));
                    u.setLname(rs.getString(8));
                }

                return m;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is how i return 2 data types?? messaging and bean..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Java, you cannot do this.

Instead, try creating a new simple object containing both a `Messaging` and a `Users`

For example

```
public class MessageBox{
    private Messaging m;
    private Users u;

    //getters and setters for both values
    public Messaging getMessage(){
        return m;
    }
}
```

and then

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
Messaging m= new Messaging();
Users u= new Users();
MessageBox mb = new MessageBox();  //<-------

...
m.setTimestamp(rs.getString(4));
m.setMsgrecipient(rs.getInt(5));
m.setUsers_userid(rs.getInt(6));
u.setFname(rs.getString(7));
u.setLname(rs.getString(8));
mb.setMessage(m);  //<-----------
mb.setUsers(u);  //<----------
...
return mb;  //<------------
```

Comment: i have it set up as you said, how can i access the different properties on a jsp page using jstl? when am tring something like ${messageContent.timestamp} - cant get back the value.

Comment: try making `MessageBox` a bean-- add a constructor and make it serializable... Not sure if this will work but it should.

Comment: thats the error i am having:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'beans.MessageBox' does not have the property 'timestamp'.

Comment: ah ok, instead of `${messageContent.timestamp}`, try `${messageContent.getMessage().timestamp}` -- the issue is that `MessageContent` doesn't contain `timestamp` it contains a `Message` and that `Message` contains `timestamp`.  So first, get the `Message` out of the `MessageContent`, and then get the `timestamp` from the `Message`

Answer (score 1):

Create a holder class for both types

```
class MessagingAndUsers
{
  private final Messaging m;
  private final Users u;

  MessagingAndUsers( Messaging m, Users u )
  {
    this.m = m;
    this.u = u;
  }

  // Getters
}
```

Now, back to your method.  First of all, looks like it needs to return a List, not a single value

```
public List<MessagingAndUsers> getMessagesByMid(int msgid) {

    String query = "SELECT msgid, msgsubject, msgcontent, timestamp, fname, lname FROM messaging INNER JOIN users ON messaging.users_userid=users.userid WHERE msgid=?;";

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
        ps.clearParameters();
        ps.setInt(1, msgid);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<MessagingAndUsers> retVal = new ArrayList<MessagingAndUsers>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Messaging m= new Messaging();
            Users u= new Users();
            m.setMsgid((rs.getInt(1)));
            m.setMsgsubject(rs.getString(2));
            m.setMsgcontent(rs.getString(3));
            m.setTimestamp(rs.getString(4));
            m.setMsgrecipient(rs.getInt(5));
            m.setUsers_userid(rs.getInt(6));
            u.setFname(rs.getString(7));
            u.setLname(rs.getString(8));

            retVal.add( new MessagingAndUsers( m, u ) );
        }

        return retVal;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
       ps.close( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i implemented the one above and i added the catch exception and ps.close() from yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it into the function as an argument and then call setters inside the function